# HTTP Status 200 with warnings?

Tags: http, rest, http-status-codes

What would you use for a successful HTTP status code but wanted to indicate some warnings? In my case, I'm making an ajax endpoint where you can add a new user. We expect a first and last name, but if there isn't one, the record will still be created and no followup to correct the situation will be expected. I just want the client to know "We created the record, and hey, BTW, the first and/or last name was blank"

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066972/http-status-code-for-success-with-errors?rq=1), but that's about actual ensuing errors, not warnings.

Comment: Why not return an error and handle it on `.fail(function()...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rest endpoint with success and a helpful warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149401/rest-endpoint-with-success-and-a-helpful-warning)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be an optimal way to put something like `{"status":"warn","meassage":"Name field is empty"}` to the response body.
There is no "warning" HTTP codes. You can of course use for example `201 CREATED` for clean creation and `200 OK` for warnings. But that's not a good way to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use for this HTTP status.

Use for this body of response. For example in JSON

```
{warnings:true, warning:'We created the record, and hey, BTW, the first and/or last name was blank'}
```