# Rest endpoint with success and a helpful warning

Tags: rest, http

I have a request from the client - when the user performs an action, there can be 3 actions:

- the action succeeds with 200 OK status
- the action fails (400) with an error message
- the action succeeds but we need to display a helpful warning message to the user. This happens when the allocated amount is almost used up.

There does not seem to be a way for REST APIs to return an indication that the action completed successfully with some helpful information that further action might fail.

Thanks

Comment: `HTTP` isn't built per your client's requirement. Return a flag in your response body instead

Comment: Would a header a'la `X-API-WARNING` be out of the question? That way you can indicate a warning without impacting the actual functionality.

Comment: Also who says that you cannot return such information in the replies body?

Answer (score 2):

REST is using HTTP methods and HTTP status to represent the status of reply, by checking HTTP status I can find code 203 I think it could be suitable for your 3rd case :

> 203 Non-Authoritative Information (since HTTP/1.1)
>       The server successfully processed the request, but is returning information that may be from another source.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP response codes are limited and I think, those to be used to indicate any generic response. To have application specific response codes or response strings, it is better to have application level response codes to be communicated via HTTP response payload.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which HTTP method you are preparing for. Using `GET` should of course not modify anything, so I'm assuming it's either `POST` or `PUT`.

For `POST`, the response should be *201 Created*. There should be a `Location` header line indicating the resource that was created.

For `PUT`, the response should be *200 OK*.

In both cases, you can return a content body, as others suggested. This body can be some status information about the current state of whatever resource you are using. Note, that this status information might be reachable explicitly by some other URI, so it can share a `mime-type` with that "status" resource.

Comment: You could also think of the Warning header, see : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.5 but I think it is not a good purpose here, as your message is useful for future request and not the current request. As others said, include in your body a "message" attribute (in json, xml or html (with a class)) so that the information can be displaied to the user.

Comment: Additionally, headers are more of an infrastructure construct, they are about some aspect of the communication itself. Caching, authentication, information about intermediaries, how the message is encoded, the type of the message, stuff like that. They are less about business-relevant information.